# Select rows certain column (C1) that is missing a particular value (V1) in a column (C2) when we group by column (C1)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres table like this:

```
C1                          C2     
-------------------------------------
apple                      No Thorns
apple                      No Thorns
orange                     Thorns
apple                      No Thorns
pineapple                  No Thorns
pineapple                  Thorns
guava                      No Thorns
guava                      Thorns
```

Now i want the names ( C1 ) of those fruits that `never` got a thorn (in C2 ) in a single query.
I apologize in advance if this is quite trivial.

Answer for above is `apple`

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select c1
from t
group by c1
having sum( (c2 = 'Thorns')::int) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
Select distinct c1 from table1
Where not exists (
Select 1 from table1  t2 where table1.c1 = t2.c1 and t2.c2 = 'Thorns')
```